# BASH - Shuffle characters in strings from file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, shuffle, lines

I have a file (`filename.txt`) with the following structure:

```
>line1
ABC
>line2
DEF
>line3
GHI
>line4
JKL
```

I would like to shuffle the characters in the strings that do **not** start wit `>`.  The output would (for example) look like the following:

```
>line1
BCA
>line2
DFE
>line3
IHG
>line4
KLJ
```

This is what I tried to shuffle the characters in a string: `sed 's/./&\n/' | shuf | tr -d "\n"` . It looks like it works but it does not take into account newlines. Moreover it executes the command on all data and not only on lines that do not start with `>`.

Comment: Is sed a requirement?

Comment: No, `sed` is not a requirement.

Comment: @Svalf: What you are asking can't be in shuf and `bash` is really slow. Could you use `awk`?

Comment: @Inian Yes, `awk` is also fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `perl` and `ruby`

```
$ # split// to get individual characters
$ # join "" to join characters with empty string
$ # if !/^>/ to apply the change only for lines not starting with >
$ # alternate: perl -MList::Util=shuffle -lne 'print /^>/ ? $_ : shuffle split//'
$ perl -MList::Util=shuffle -lpe '$_=join "", shuffle split// if !/^>/' ip.txt 
>line1
CBA
>line2
FED
>line3
IHG
>line4
JKL

$ # $_.chars to get individual characters
$ # * "" to join array elements with empty string
$ ruby -lpe '$_ = $_.chars.shuffle * "" if !/^>/' ip.txt 
>line1
BAC
>line2
EDF
>line3
GHI
>line4
JKL
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if the file had more lines in-between the lines starting with `>`, how could I use ruby in order to shuffle through all the lines in between lines starting with `>` and not line by line?

Comment: I am not getting what you mean by `shuffle through all the lines`... in any case, try modifying the solutions (this one + plus other answers) to suit your need.. if that doesn't help, ask another question with appropriate samples so that others can help :)

Answer (score 2):

**`awk`** + **`coreutils`** approach:

```
awk '/^[^>]/{ system("echo "$1"| fold -w1 | shuf | tr -d \047\n\047"); print ""; next }1' file
```

Sample output:

```
>line1
BAC
>line2
EDF
>line3
HGI
>line4
KLJ
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one in GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v seed=$RANDOM '                   # get some randomness from shell
function cmp_randomize(i1, v1, i2, v2) {  # random for traversal function
    return (2 - 4 * rand())               # from 12.2.1 Controlling Array Traversal
}                                         # of Gnu awk docs
BEGIN {
    srand(seed)                           # use the seed, Luke
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="cmp_randomize" # use above defined function
}
/^[^>]/ {                                 # if starts with anything but >
    split($0,a,"")                        # split to hash a
    for(i in a)                           # iterate a in random order
        printf "%s", a[i]                 # output
    print ""                              # newline
    next                                  # next record
}1' file                                  # output > starting records
>line1
CAB
>line2
DFE
>line3
GIH
>line4
LKJ
```

Answer (score 1):

For `GNU sed`:

```
$ cat filename.txt
>line1
ABC
>line2
DEF
>line3
GHI
>line4
JKL
$ sed -r "/^[^>]/s/.*/grep -o . <<< & |sort -R |tr -d '\n'/e" filename.txt
>line1
ABC
>line2
FDE
>line3
HGI
>line4
LKJ
$ sed -r "/^[^>]/s/.*/grep -o . <<< & |shuf |tr -d '\n'/e" filename.txt
>line1
BCA
>line2
FDE
>line3
HIG
>line4
JKL
```

Edit: `sed` works all the same on all `(GNU sed) 4.2.2`, we can print the raw command string generated by sed by removing the `e` modifier:

```
sed -r '/^[^>]/s/.*/grep -o . <<< & |shuf |tr -d "\n"/' filename.txt
>line1
grep -o . <<< ABC |shuf |tr -d "
"
>line2
grep -o . <<< DEF |shuf |tr -d "
"
>line3
grep -o . <<< GHI |shuf |tr -d "
"
>line4
grep -o . <<< JKL |shuf |tr -d "
"
```

Then, the `e` modifier of `s` command of `sed` will call `sh` to execute it. The `sh` on `CentOS` is a symbolic link to `bash`, but on Ubuntu it is a symbolic link to `dash`, and `dash` maybe not support `<<<` (`here-string`).

```
# on Ubuntu, enter into sh terminal:
$ grep -o . <<< JKL |shuf |tr -d '\n'
sh: 2: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
$ echo JKL |grep -o . |shuf |tr -d '\n'
KLJ
```

So, I need to modify my answer to work for both `bash` and `dash`:

```
$ sed -r '/^[^>]/s/.*/echo -n & |grep -o . |shuf |tr -d "\n"/e' filename.txt
>line1
ACB
>line2
DFE
>line3
IHG
>line4
LJK
```

Simple explanations:

1. `/^[^>]/`: force `sed` to deal with the lines which starts (`^`) with NOT a `>` (`[^>]`).
2. `s/.*/echo -n & |grep -o . |shuf |tr -d "\n"/`:  `.*` is the whole line, use `&` to hold it in substitute, so `&` is the whole origin line, then generate a plain command string `echo -n ORIGIN_LINE |grep -o . |shuf |tr -d "\n"`, which can shuffle a line.
3. finally, use the `e` modifier of `s` command to execute the plain command string generated above.

Comment: which sed version and shell? I get `Syntax error: redirection unexpected` on GNU sed + bash

Comment: @Sundeep it works fine on CentOS7 with `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`, but not for ubuntu 16.04 with `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`, I'm confused...

Comment: I am surprised that this is even possible with sed.. I thought one couldn't apply `e` to backreferences like `&`, `\1` etc

Comment: I have modified my answer. @Sundeep

Comment: Today I learnt that we can use other commands within `sed`. Nice!

Comment: Regex before `s` was new for me. Even this works: `sed -r 's/^([^>].*)/echo -n & | grep -o . | shuf | tr -d "\n"/e' sample.txt`

Comment: I have added explanations. @AliYousuf

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^>/b;s/./&\n/g;s/.$//;s/.*/echo "&"|shuf/e' file
```

Print lines beginning with `>` but do not process. Otherwise, insert newlines between each character in the current line and remove the last unwanted newline. Then `echo` the file produced and pipe it throught the `shuf` command (sort -R may be substituted if necessary) and print the result.

N.B. This solution uses the GNU specific `e` flag on the substitution command, however the result could be passed to a shell, like so:

```
sed '/^>/s/.*/echo "&"/;t;s/./&\n/g;s/.$//;s/.*/echo "&"|shuf/' file | sh
```