# BASH - Shuffle characters in strings from several rows

Tags: ruby, bash, shuffle

I have a file (filename.txt) with the following structure:

```
>line1
ABC
DEF
GHI
>line2
JKL
MNO
PQR
>line3
STU
VWX
YZ
```

I would like to shuffle the characters in the strings that **do not** start wit `>`. The output would (for example) look like the following:

```
>line1
DGC
FEI
HBA
>line2
JRP
OKN
QML
>line3
SZV
YXT
UW
```

This is what I tried to shuffle the characters for each `>line[number]`: `ruby -lpe '$_ = $_.chars.shuffle * "" if !/^>/' filename.txt`. The command works (see my post [BASH - Shuffle characters in strings from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555930/bash-shuffle-characters-in-strings-from-file)) but it shuffles line by line. I was wondering how I could modify the command to shuffle characters between **all** strings of each `>line[number]`). Using `ruby` is not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to solve the problem: how to shuffle all characters in multiple lines:

```
echo -e 'ABC\nDEF\nGHI' |grep -o . |shuf |tr -d '\n'
GDAFHEIBC
```

and, we also need an array to record the length of each line in origin strings.

```
s=GDAFHEIBC
lens=(3 3 3)
start=0
for len in "${lens[@]}"; do
    echo ${s:${start}:${len}}
    ((start+=len))
done
GDA
FHE
IBC
```

So, the origin multiple lines:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

have been shuffled to:

```
GDA
FHE
IBC
```

Now, we can do our jobs:

```
lens=()
string=""

function shuffle_lines {
    local start=0
    local shuffled_string=$(grep -o . <<< ${string} |shuf |tr -d '\n')
    for len in "${lens[@]}"; do
        echo ${shuffled_string:${start}:${len}}
        ((start+=len))
    done
    lens=()
    string=""
}

while read -r line; do
    if [[ "${line}" =~ ^\> ]]; then
        shuffle_lines
        echo "${line}"
    else
        string+="${line}"
        lens+=(${#line})
    fi
done <filename.txt

shuffle_lines
```

Examples:

```
$ cat filename.txt
>line1
ABC
DEF
GHI
>line2
JKL
MNO
PQR
>line3
STU
VWX
YZ
>line4
0123
456
78
9
$ ./solution.sh
>line1
HFG
BED
AIC
>line2
JOP
KMQ
RLN
>line3
UVW
TYZ
XS
>line4
1963
245
08
7
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This works perfectly fine. But why is there a `shuffle_lines` in the last line of the code?

Comment: @Svalf If current line starts with the `>` character, we need to shuffle all the lines(kept in the variable `string`) which doesn't start with `>`, and then print the line which starts with the `>`; otherwise, we use a variable `string` to keep all the lines starting with not `>`. But, if the last line of your `filename.txt` doesn't start with the `>`, we also need to shuffle the lines which doesn't start with the `>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# echo > output.txt         # uncomment to write in a file output.txt

mix(){
    {
        echo "$title"
        line="$( fold -w1 <<< "$line"  | shuf  )"
        echo "${line//$'\n'}" | fold -w3
    }  # >> output.txt         # uncomment to write in a file output.txt
    unset line
}

while read -r; do
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^\> ]]; then
        mix
        title="$REPLY"
    else
        line+="$REPLY"
    fi
done < filename.txt
mix       # final mix after loop's exit, otherwise line3 will be not mixed

exit
```

edited with comment of [gniourf-gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf)

Comment: Why so many `echo`s ? In `mix`, `echo "${line//$'n'}" | fold -w3` is enough. You don't need to wrap this in another `echo`...

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your comment. which is another echo?

Comment: `echo "$( echo ${line//$'\n'} | fold -w3 )"` vs just `echo "${line//$'n'}" | fold -w3`

Comment: ok, well seen. it was a draft, I changed this line at the last moment.

Answer (score 0):

First create a test file.

```
str =<<FINI
>line1
ABC
DEF
GHI
>line2
JKL
MNO
PQR
>line3
STU
VWX
YZ
FINI

File.write('test', str)
  #=> 56
```

Now read the file and perform the desired operations.

```
result = File.read('test').split(/(>line\d+)/).map do |s|
  if s.match?(/\A(?:|>line\d+)\z/)
    s
  else
    a = s.scan(/\p{Lu}/).shuffle
    s.gsub(/\p{Lu}/) { a.shift }
  end
end.join
  # ">line1\nECF\nHIA\nGBD\n>line2\nJNP\nKLR\nOQM\n>line3\nTXY\nUZV\nSW\n"

puts result
>line1
ECF
HIA
GBD
>line2
JNP
KLR
OQM
>line3
TXY
UZV
SW
```

To do this from the command convert the code to a string with statements separated by a semicolon.

```
ruby -e "puts (File.read('test').split(/(>line\d+)/).map do |s|; if s.match?(/\A(?:|>line\d+)\z/); s; else; a = s.scan(/\p{Lu}/).shuffle; s.gsub(/\p{Lu}/) { a.shift }; end; end).join"
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = File.read('test')
  #=> ">line1\nABC\nDEF\nGHI\n>line2\nJKL\nMNO\nPQR\n>line3\nSTU\nVWX\nYZ\n"
b = a.split(/(>line\d+)/)
  #=> ["", ">line1", "\nABC\nDEF\nGHI\n", ">line2", "\nJKL\nMNO\nPQR\n",
  #    ">line3", "\nSTU\nVWX\nYZ\n"]
```

Notice that the regular expression that is `split`'s argument places `>line\d+` within a capture group. Without that, `">line1"`, `">line2"` and `">line3"` would not be included in `b`.

```
c = b.map do |s|
  if s.match?(/\A(?:|>line\d+)\z/)
    s
  else
    a = s.scan(/\p{Lu}/).shuffle
    s.gsub(/\p{Lu}/) { a.shift }
  end
end
  #=> ["", ">line1", "\nEAC\nIHB\nDGF\n", ">line2", "\nKQJ\nROL\nMPN\n",
  #    ">line3", "\nSUY\nXTV\nZW\n"]
c.join
  #=> ">line1\nEAC\nIHB\nDGF\n>line2\nKQJ\nROL\nMPN\n>line3\nSUY\nXTV\nZW\n"
```

Now consider more closely the calculation of `c`. The first element of `b` is passed to the block and the block variable `s` is set to its value:

```
s = ""
```

We then compute

```
s.match?(/\A(?:|>line\d+)\z/)
  #=> true
```

so `""` is returned from the block. The regular expression can be expressed as follows.

```
/
\A          # match the beginning of the string
(?:         # begin a non-capture group
            # match an empty space
  |         # or
  >line\d+  # match '>line' followed by one or more digits
)           # end non-capture group
\z          # match the end of the string
/x          # free-spacing regex definition mode.
```

Within the non-capture group an empty space was matched.

The next element of `b` is then passed to the block.

```
s = ">line1"
```

Again

```
s.match?(/\A(?:|>line\d+)\z/)
  #=> true
```

so `s` is return from the block.

Now the third element of `b` is passed to the block. (Finally, something interesting.)

```
s = "\nABC\nDEF\nGHI\n"
d = s.scan(/\p{Lu}/)
  #=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
a = d.shuffle
  #=> ["D", "C", "G", "H", "B", "F", "I", "E", "A"]
s.gsub(/\p{Lu}/) { a.shift }
  #=> "\nDCG\nHBF\nIEA\n"
```

The remaining calculations are similar.